# Limiting GCP Client Libraries for Go calls to specific a organization

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform

I am writing a tool that will list all my Google Cloud projects using the [client libraries for Go](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go).

More specifically, I am creating a [`cloudresourcemanager`](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/cloudresourcemanager/v1) service and then I am listing the projects based on that (more or less) as follows:

```golang
import (
   crm "google.golang.org/api/cloudresourcemanager/v1"
)

crmService, err := crm.NewService(ctx)
projectsService := crm.NewProjectsService(crmService)
projectsListCall := projectsService.List()
projectsListCall.Context(ctx)
listProjectsResponse, err := projectsListCall.Do()
```

The problem is that my application's default credentials provide me access to multiple organizations, so the process above will list all projects across all organizations I have access to.

I therefore want to pass the organization option as a flag, but nowhere in the [`cloudresourcemanager`](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/cloudresourcemanager/v1) documentation is there a hint that this is possible.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: You can specify a filter and limit to `parent.id`. If you have Org/Folder/Project, I am not sure as the filter will limit to children of `parent.id`. https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/cloudresourcemanager/v1#ProjectsListCall.Filter

Comment: I infer that this requires a priori knowledge of the `id` of the parent resource (be it an org or a folder)...

Comment: Yes, but you can list the organizations and pick the one you want to filter on.